# Using a list to create columns on MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use a list to create different columns using its names on a MySQL database, but I'm running into a few issues.

My code so far is:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect("localhost", "***", "***", "tutorial")

c = conn.cursor()

dicts = {'id': 5141, 'product_id': 193, 'price_ex_tax': '90.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'type': 'physical', 'ebay_item_id': '', 'option_set_id': 38, 'total_inc_tax': '198.0000', 'quantity': 2, 'price_inc_tax': '99.0000', 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'UQ Bachelor Graduation Gown Set', 'configurable_fields': [], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000', 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'wrapping_message': '', 'order_address_id': 964, 'total_ex_tax': '180.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '9.0000', 'is_bundled_product ': False, 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'parent_order_product_id': None, 'event_date': '', 'total_tax': '18.0000', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '198.0000', 'product_options': [{'id': 4208, 'display_name': 'Gown size (based on height)', 'name': 'Bachelor gown size', 'display_value': 'L (175-182cm)', 'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'option_id': 19, 'value': '77', 'product_option_id': 175, 'order_product_id': 5141}, {'id': 4209, 'display_name': 'Hood', 'name': 'H-QLD-BAC-STD', 'display_value': 'UQ Bachelor Hood', 'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'option_id': 42, 'value': '119', 'product_option_id': 176, 'order_product_id': 5141}, {'id': 4210, 'display_name': 'Trencher size (based on head circumference)', 'name': 'Trencher size', 'display_value': 'M (53-54cm)', 'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'option_id': 20, 'value': '81', 'product_option_id': 177, 'order_product_id': 5141}], 'base_price': '99.0000', 'sku': 'S-QLD-BAC-STD', 'return_id': 0, 'applied_discounts': [{'id': 'coupon', 'amount': 30}], 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'is_refunded': False, 'weight': '2.0000', 'order_id': 615496}

keys_from_dictionary = list(dicts.keys())

for x in keys_from_dictionary:
    query = "ALTER TABLE taula ADD %s VARCHAR(255)".format()
    c.execute(query, x)
    conn.commit()

 c.execute("SELECT * FROM taula")

 rows = c.fetchall()

 for eachRow in rows:
    print(eachRow)

print(keys_from_dictionary)
```

I get this error: 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fixed_shipping_cost' VARCHAR(255)' at line 1")

The problem is it adds the apostrophe so the SQL query fails.

I tried to change the code a bit to:

```
query = "ALTER TABLE taula ADD {} VARCHAR(255)".format()
```

But then I get:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

How can I run this loop to create a column for each value from the list?

EDIT:

The error I get when I put the parameter:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Filipe\code\bigAnalysis\database\dbconnectex002.py", line 13, in 
    c.execute(query, x)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 133, in execute
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = "ALTER TABLE taula ADD %s VARCHAR(255)".format(x)
c.execute(query,())
```

The hint is finish manipulating the whole sql beforehand and pass an empty tuple as the second parameter to execute().

Comment: It executes just fine on mysql console!

Comment: @iamfbpt Is it because you have duplicated columns?

Comment: No. The problem is that the formatted string adds apostrophes ('') to the query, therefore, the query fails. I need to be able to pass just the value from each position on the list, for instance:
Instead of : 'id'
I need to pass: id

Comment: @iamfbpt Sorry I am mistaken it with sqlite. But here is the code. Finish manipulating the whole sql and execute without parameter any more.

Comment: always try to provide explanations with your answers in order to improve the quality of your post.